# If URI is a file link then prepend with folder else rewrite with index.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess

#### Dir stracture

```
- dist
  - js
  - css
- index.php
- .htaccess
```

I don't want to move `index.php` to `/dist` because the dist files are build by Vue.js and excluded from git and etc.

I'm trying to get this working for hours with help of Google and Apache docs but failing.

#### My .htaccess for now:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(app|dict|ns|tmp)\/|\.ini$ - [R=404]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .(css|js)$
RewriteRule ^(.*.(css|js))$ /dist/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

It rewrites all needed requests to the `index.php`, but js and css throws an error:

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at [no address given] to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Apache logs:

```
[Fri Aug 16 23:10:06.973003 2019] [core:error] [pid 10716:tid 996] [client 127.0.0.1:2106] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

As the title says I want to prepend all the assets with `\dist` folder otherwise rewrite to `index.php`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at backtrace and this is what I've got after changes:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(app|dict|ns|tmp)\/|\.ini$ - [R=404]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(?!dist\/?).*.(css|js|map)$
RewriteRule ^((?!dist\/).*.(css|js|map))$ /dist/$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

It works

The thing is

> A RewriteRule loops when the target of the rule matches the initial rewrite pattern. For example, if you were to rewrite all URLs starting with "foo" to "foo.php", then "foo.php" would also get rewritten to "foo.php", and so on, forever.

You should look in [the source](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HTTPD/RewriteLooping) if you ran in to this.